# Determining a vector that is perpendicular to only one given vector.

Tags: vector-spaces

I am stuck on a question again that asks to determine a vector that is perpendicular to the one given: a = [1,2,3].

I am familiar with the dot product but not the cross product so can anyone help me with this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the dot product to find an infinite family of such vectors.  Suppose that $(x,y,z)$ is perpendicular to $(1,2,3)$.  Then:

$$x+2y+3z=0$$

Or in other words, for any real $s$ and $t$, the vector $(3s,3t,-s-2t)$ is such a vector.  Geometrically, it makes sense that our solutions should makeup a two-dimensional object, as they are the plane whose normal vector is $(1,2,3)$.

Comment: Could you please explain to me how the (3s, 3t, -s-2t) came about?

Comment: @Ol'Reliable: Let $x=s$ and $y=t$, and rearrange the equation for $z$.  I multiplied everything by $3$ to avoid fractions.

Comment: ok ok, that makes sense, thanks!